# Why does console log not work after a return statement?

Tags: javascript, html

I am testing my code and I can't figure out why it's not working.

I created buttons in HTML for each choice and created a function in JavaScript for each choice. I included onclick in HTML to call the respective functions and try to log the choice in the console so I could see if it was working but nothing happens when I click the userRock button.

I would greatly appreciate some help. Thank you.

```js
let userChoice;

function userRock () {
  userChoice = 'rock';
  return userChoice;
  console.log(userChoice);
}

function userPaper () {
  userChoice = 'paper';
  return userChoice;
}

function userScissors () {
  userChoice = 'scissors';
  return userChoice;
}

function userLizard () {
  userChoice = 'lizard';
  return userChoice;
}

function userSpock () {
  userChoice = 'spock';
  return userChoice;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "container">
      <button id = "rock" onclick = "userRock()">Rock</button> <button id = "paper" onclick = "userPaper()">Paper</button> <button id = "scissors" onclick = "userScissors()">Scissors</button> <button id = "lizard" onclick = "userLizard()">Lizard</button> <button id = "spock" onclick = "userSpock()">Spock</button>
    </div>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/zenturtle/pen/YzqXVbB?editors=1111

Comment: You're not using the return values of the functions anywhere.

Comment: `return` statement before each `console.log()` statement means that each `console.log()` is un-reachable statement in your code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: The console should tell you what the problem is when you open it: unreachable code after return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct there is no syntactic error in it however do note that whatever code you write after `return` statement will never get executed. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#:%7E:text=When%20a%20return%20statement%20is,where%20x%20is%20a%20number.&text=If%20the%20value%20is%20omitted%2C%20undefined%20is%20returned%20instead.) when a return statement is used in a function body, the execution of the function is stopped. So just move the `console.log` above your return statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have return statement before console.log(), which makes the console.log() unreachable.

Update this

```
function userRock () {
  userChoice = 'rock';
  return userChoice;
  console.log(userChoice); // unreachable
}
```

to

```
function userRock () {
  userChoice = 'rock';
  console.log(userChoice);
  return userChoice;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Return statements**

Note that in most programming languages `return` is a special [keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

A function ends it's execution when the return statement is reached.

In your code, when you click on the button that triggers your `userRock()` function, the following code will execute from top to bottom.

```
function userRock () {
  userChoice = 'rock';
  return userChoice;
  console.log(userChoice);
}
```

First it will assign the string `rock` to your variable `userChoice`
Then you return the choice.
Then nothing happens because you returned a value with your function and that is where the function stops.

**What you can do to fix it:**

first console.log the variable, then return it.

**Working example:**

```
function userRock () {
  userChoice = 'rock';
  console.log(userChoice);
  return userChoice;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

return points after console

```js
let userChoice;

function userRock() {
  userChoice = 'rock';
  console.log(userChoice);
  return userChoice;
}

function userPaper() {
  userChoice = 'paper';
  console.log(userChoice);
  return userChoice;
}

function userScissors() {
  userChoice = 'scissors';
  console.log(userChoice);
  return userChoice;
}

function userLizard() {
  userChoice = 'lizard';
  console.log(userChoice);
  return userChoice;
}

function userSpock() {
  userChoice = 'spock';
  console.log(userChoice);
  return userChoice;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "container">
      <button id = "rock" onclick="userRock()">Rock</button> <button id = "paper" onclick = "userPaper()">Paper</button> <button id = "scissors" onclick = "userScissors()">Scissors</button> <button id = "lizard" onclick = "userLizard()">Lizard</button> <button id = "spock" onclick = "userSpock()">Spock</button>
    </div>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```